# Error : JavaScript Function Add to class dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to web development.
Today I learn about classes (function) in JavaScript. I got an error how to call dynamically added method.

My code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    function MyMethod(name, fn) {
        var str = "MyFunction1.prototype." + name + "= fn;";
        eval(str);
    }

    function MyFunction1() {
    
        MyMethod("start", function () { return "hi"; });

        var abc = this.start(); //gives error 
        

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="MyFunction1()"/>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Here when I click the input button then not able to call the dynamically added function
How can I call the `start()` function that I added here.

Please help me.

Comment: The value of `this` isn't what you expect. Have you tried `onclick="new MyFunction1()"`? I'd suggest reading about the [use of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), and about [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Also, dynamically adding functions using a separate method that uses `eval()` with a hard-coded `"MyFunction1.prototype"` seems like an overly confusing way to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in `MyFunction1` referes to the *global* object in that case(for browsers it is `window`) , because you call `MyFunction1`  as function and you don't create an object by using `new MyFunction1()`.

Another thing to be noted. You should not use `eval` when it is possible to do it without eval.

You can do the same thing using:

```
function MyMethod(name, fn) {
    MyFunction1.prototype[name] = fn;
}
```

Using `eval` prevents you from using optimization tools or tools to validate your code. At least most of these tools don't take `eval` into account or even give a warning about that you are using it.

Comment: Hi , It resolved .Thanks for the gret help i did :    function fnOnload() {
            MyMethod("start", function () { return "hi"; });
        }

        function MyMethod(name, fn) {
            var str = "MyFunction1.prototype." + name + "= fn;";
            eval(str);
        }

        function MyFunction1() {


        }
        function MyFunction2() 
        {
            var aa = new MyFunction1();
            var answee = aa.start();
        }

Answer (score 2):

without changing your code you can do as follow , but I say it would be helpful if you read about invocations types and about this variable.

```
function MyMethod(name, fn) {
  MyFunction1.prototype[name]= fn;
  return MyFunction1.prototype;
}
function MyFunction1() {
  var myPrototype= MyMethod("start", function () { return "hi"; });
  var returnValue = myPrototype.start();
  console.log(returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "new" before your onclick call to MyFunction1, creating an instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

It reseolved I did

Hi , It resolved .Thanks for the gret help i did :

```
  function fnOnload() {
            MyMethod("start", function () { return "hi"; });
        }

    function MyMethod(name, fn) {
        var str = "MyFunction1.prototype." + name + "= fn;";
        eval(str);
    }

    function MyFunction1() {


    }
    function MyFunction2() 
    {
        var aa = new MyFunction1();
        var answee = aa.start();
    }
```

and in click of button i callled function MyFunction2()

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use the `var str = "MyFunction1.prototype." + name + "= fn;";eval(str);` and use `MyFunction1.prototype[name] = fn;` instead.